# Website for high school student to self-teach programming

Tags: web-apps, programming

My nephew wants to dabble in programming to see if he likes it.  I'm a knowledgeable programmer available to assist him to a degree, but he needs some form of structured work.

I'm wondering if anyone can suggest a good site that has structured assignments in a **newbie friendly language** that he could work off of to do some self-directed learning; **using me only to help explain/debug things he is struggling with**?

In particular I'm looking for a site that offers programming assignments appropriate to his level, ideally with some unit tests to confirm rather or not his program successfully meets the objective of the assignment?

Comment: Sorry, [asking for websites is off topic](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/191/can-i-ask-for-recommended-websites) here.

Comment: But, Google is your friend.  Code Academy, Coursera ... even Youtbue ... But, really, only you can judge what he is capable of at any given time and structrue a program for him. Btw, how old is he?

Comment: IMO dsollen is actually asking for a web app, not a website. I'd say Code Academy, Coursera, Khan Academy and even Youtube are all web apps, not websites. If he was asking for a programming reference site (e.g. htmlrocks.com) then yes he'd be off-topic but as it stands I think this question is wholly on-topic.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions you've already gotten, if the language is Java (or Python), consider http://codingbat.com

Comment: Google has [a technical guide to online courses](https://www.google.co.in/about/careers/students/guide-to-technical-development.html) that's worth a look as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://freecodecamp.com for web development, javascript, npm, node js, html & css